# how to click a button under a nested div using xpath and class in behat3

Tags: php, selenium, laravel-5, behat, mink

I have a nested div structure with a button element in it. I want to check the click and redirect functionality on it via behat test cases, But I am not able to test it as error shows up.

My page HTML is something like this -

```
<div id="divSubmit1">
      <div id="subDivSubmit1">...</div>
      <div class="row  mt-20 ">...</div>
      <div class="row mt-20">
             <div class="col-xs-offset-7 col-xs-5 mt-20 mb-10 text-center">
                 <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg mt-20" type="submit" name="cmd_btn_submit" onclick="return check_input()">Submit
                     <span class="btn-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></span></button>
             </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Have tried the following

This is my step in feature file

```
And I click on button "cmd_btn_submit"
```

and my context file has

```
     * @And I click on button :arg1
     * @Then I click on button :arg1
     */
    public function iClickOnButton($arg1)
    {
       $this->getSession()->getPage()->find("xpath", "//button[div[@id='divSubmit1'][contains(text(),'".$arg1."')]]
")->click();

}
```

Getting this error,

```
And I click on button "cmd_btn_submit"                                                                                   # Shop\Features\Context\FeatureContext::iClickOnButton()
      Fatal error: Call to a member function click() on null (Behat\Testwork\Call\Exception\FatalThrowableError)
```

Comment: the element which you are trying to click is not found with your provided `xpath`

Comment: The xpath `"//button[div[@id='divSubmit1'][contains(text(),'".$arg1."')]]"` makes no sense to me. Why is it trying to find a DIV inside the square brackets for the `button` element. The square brackets are usually reserved for matching properties of the current element, not attempting to match child elements.

Comment: @GregBurghardt -- I found the xpath reference from google. Can you please help me out in writing the correct one or any link reference would do too. Actually, I am new to this behat thing and this is my first code.

Comment: Can you post the HTML you are trying to get Selenium to interact with?

Comment: @GregBurghardt - updated my question with the page HTML requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XPath is wrong, plus your argument needs to be button text, not the Id of the button.

Your xpath should be:

```php
"//div[@id='divSubmit1']//button[contains(text(), '$arg1')]"
```

And your cucumber step should be:

```
And I click on button "Submit"
```

Answer (score 0):

As you defined is not very efficient, you are defining a step with parameter that will match only a button(since your xpath is based on the id of the section) or at most 2 buttons if you have a cancel option.

Better say `I submit the form` with not parameters.

If you want a general step you need to get rid of the `id` from the xpath.

> For general button click better use the step that is already defined in mink
>
> `I press "button_identifier"` that works with `id|name|title|alt|value`

Beside this, for your custom steps, you need to handle the exceptions, specially the fatal ones like in your case, fatal exception => suite ends.

You have to wait for the element and make sure is present, and after that to do some actions on it.

Comment: Thanks for the help @lauda. However, this was also not working. I had tried with the `I press` step function earlier too for this. It seemed to work for other forms/pages except this one.
I reolved it by the solution given by @Greg Burghardt